# JS regex name highlighting

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating an auto complete and I'm having a little problem the results highlighting. You see my searching algorithm is very generous and ignores apostrophes in the result so therefore a query like `joes` will match `Joe's`. The search algorithm is taken care of and now comes the highlighting part. I wanted to make the matched pattern bold.

Let's say I had an original unformatted result: `Joe’s` (*take note the rsquo \u2019)* and I wanted to highlight it like this: `Joe’s`, for the following queries `joes`, `joe's`, and `joe’s` *(rsquo \u2019)*

I included the right side single quotation mark in the query because you wouldn't know if someone was copying a query from a word document or something.

I could easily do it by ignoring the fact that the quotation marks are there in both search/result strings but that would mess up the whole point of the search when you accidentally type something like `joes'` or even worse `jo'es`. So I somehow need to preserve the quote position. Also please take note that an apostrophe can also be anywhere in the unformatted result string like so `Suq'Ata`.

Here are a list of scenarios:

---

- String: `Liliana's`
- Queries: `lilianas`, `liliana's`
- Result: `Liliana's`

---

- String: `Suq'Ata`
- Queries: `suqat`, `suq'at`
- Result: `Suq'Ata`

---

- String: `Telim'Tor's`
- Queries: `telimt`, `telim't`
- Result: `Telim'Tor's`

---

It should be noted that the position of the quotes in the query is important whereas when you misplace a quote in your query, it should not match at all. So it's either you have the correct quote position, or no quotes at all to highlight the original string.

I actually don't mind if a proposed solution is to break apart each letter and loop through it (have thought about it) since I'll just be doing this to up to 5 strings at a given time. I'm looking forward to your suggestions!

Comment: Should the first result be **Liliana's**, since the original string is `Liliana's`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated question specs from asker:**

1. If the user's query has a quote, its position must match the quote of the original string. Eg. query "jo'es" does not match original string "Joe's".
2. We only need to bother matching the start of the query with the start of the original string.

---

I can think of better algorithms, but to start here's a quick and dirty first stab at it, using the naive loop over each letter method:

```
var quotesRegex = /['\u2019]/g;

function highlightMatch(origStr, query) {        
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; ++i, ++j) {
        // Query has a quote; it needs to be in the same position as origStr
        if (query.charAt(i).match(quotesRegex)) { 
            if (!origStr.charAt(j).match(quotesRegex)) {
                return origStr;  // quote position mismatch
            }
            continue;
        }

        while (origStr.charAt(j).match(quotesRegex)) {
            j++;                
        }

        if (origStr.charAt(j).toLowerCase() != query.charAt(i)) {
            return origStr;
        }
    }

    return "<b>" + origStr.slice(0, j) + "</b>" + origStr.slice(j);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FFt2T/6/

Comment: I forgot to mention that the query string has to match only the beginning of the result, like in my query examples. Also, to emphasize, the quote position should be preserve so as when you misplace a quote on your query, it shouldn't match at all. So it's either put the correct quote position or not use a quote at all. I guess that's not a far-off trek from the solution you proposed, I will have a try and report what happens.

Comment: @voldomazta So if the user types "Jo'es" that should _not_ match "Joes"?

Comment: Correct, if a quote is misplaced, we just return the original string.

Comment: @voldomazta Alright, updated the JSFiddle and my answer to match those requirements. Please also update your question.

Comment: I got more problems when it comes to Aeligs, would you care to help? Maybe for a fee perhaps.

Comment: @voldomazta If it's unrelated, post another question. I have to go to sleep now. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5315/discussion-between-voldomazta-and-divad12)